# The Optimal Urinal Strategy

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Here is an [interactive page](http://www.jameshoskin.co.uk/games/urinal.html) describing the problem and an [academic paper](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~kranakis/Papers/urinal.pdf) going over the mathematics.

The problem can be roughly described as follows.

Given an arbitrary-length array of boolean values representing `n` adjacent urinals, with values of `true` indicating *occupied* and values of `false` indicating *vacant*, how would you construct an algorithm to populate this array, given any configuration, while:

- Maximizing the 'privacy' of each occupant by keeping one as far as possible from other urinators on either side.
- Maintaining this privacy for as long as possible by ensuring the configuration becomes saturated at the last possible time.
- Faced with multiple suboptimal choices, prioritizing urinals without an adjacent urinal on either side over a merely unoccupied adjacent urinal.

I marked this javascript for simplicity, but any code or pseudo-code would be fine.

```
var urinals = Array
    .apply(null, new Array(n))
    .map(Boolean.prototype.valueOf,false);
```

---

edit - found a related problem here:

[Optimal Seating Arrangement Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572112/optimal-seating-arrangement-algorithm/12572232#12572232)

Comment: @AlienArrays - For the sake of simplicity, horse troth urinals, shrubbery and holes in the ground are excluded. Also, assume a perfectly spherical, frictionless pisser.

Comment: @Greg, this question is a perfect example of "unclear" abuse now that some other close reasons are gone. See the endless discussion on meta (basically I think people have just stopped looking for fitting close reasons and if they don't like something they just close it for whatever reason). Personally I thought this was an interesting and thought-provoking question and would have liked to answer it (and am even toying with the idea of basing a casual game off of it).

Comment: @DaggNabbit Yup. I'm actually trying to use this for an online game of blackjack. There's nothing critical about it and I could do without, or with a suboptimal solution; just thought it might be a fun problem that might have been a welcome break from all misplaced semicolons and "how do I do this in jquery" questions. I'd post it in cs, but that's like asking a physicist to tell you how to fix your car.

Comment: I just stumbled over the Perl module [Acme::Urinal](https://metacpan.org/pod/Acme::Urinal). It uses slightly different rules, though.

Answer (score 1):

As close as I have to a solution:

```
var urinalFinder = function(urinals){
    var gaps = new Array(), last = null;
    for(var i = 0; i < urinals.length; i++){
        last = gaps.length ? gaps[gaps.length - 1] : 0;
        if(last < 0 && !urinals[i] || last > 0 && !!urinals[i] || last == 0) 
            gaps.push(0); // push if new sequence of vacant or occupied
        // negatives are occupied count & positives vacant count
        gaps[gaps.length - 1] += !!urinals[i] ? -1 : 1; 
    }

    // find the first index of the largest gap
    var maxGapSize = Math.max.apply(Math, gaps),
        maxGapGapsIdx = gaps.indexOf(maxGapSize),
        isFirst = maxGapGapsIdx === 0,
        isLast = maxGapGapsIdx === gaps.length - 1,
        maxGapIdx = 0;

    if(maxGapSize < 1) return false; // no gaps available

    var gapPoint = maxGapSize > 3 
            ? Math.ceil(maxGapSize / 3) // per xkcd suggestion
            : isFirst && maxGapSize === 2
                ? 1
                : isLast && maxGapSize === 2 ? 2 : Math.ceil(maxGapSize / 2);

    // find where our chosen gap begins in input array
    for(var i = 0; i < maxGapGapsIdx; i++)
        maxGapIdx += Math.abs(gaps[i]);

    var result = maxGapIdx + gapPoint - 1; // arrays are zero-indexed

    return result;
};
```

For example, applied to filling an array of 9 vacant spaces will fill them like this:

```
var foo = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; // nine values
for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++)
    foo[urinalFinder(foo)] = i+1;

[4, 6, 1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 5]
```

Does not always produce optimal results (sometimes a different placement could allow saturation a few moves later) and does not favor end urinals, but does a pretty good job fanning values around and keeping a minimum buffer for just about as long as possible.